# Can we automate a non English site using Protractor tool

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

In our project, we can set the language as English or French. So i am able to automate when the site is in English language. Can we automate the Application if it is in French language? if so how can i do it? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see difference. Use xpath or css regularly, if you need to locate an element with a text, use that text in French instead of english.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..so we need a French Keyboard in order to locate an element with a text? or what is other methods for using French text? Can we pass French text from a file to a .js file? If so can you please give me brief idea about that?

Comment: Ok so it is not about the real language it is about keyboard...It is then related to encoding sstandard, find and use UTF-8 for encoding in protractor and VC, there should not be any isses.